# Arduino a/c control by temperature

Tags: arduino, temperature, infrared

I need to power on my a/c when the temperature is lower than a number and viceversa power off it when the temperature become higher than another number. So I've tried this sketch

```
  if (DHT.temperature,1 >= 0 &&  DHT.temperature,1 <=18)
  irsend.sendRaw(ON, sizeof(ON)/sizeof(int),khz);
  else if
  irsend.sendRaw(OFF, sizeof(OFF)/sizeof(int),khz);
```

but it send the OFF command every loop cycle given that the temperature don't change immediately. Is possible to send the ON and OFF command only once for cycle and wait that it change for send the other command? I've thinked to store the last sent command but I don't know how to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written your if statement properly. Also add a test for if it is on already. You can do it like this:

This will have to be a global variable so it doesn't get destroyed outside your loop below.

```
boolean isOn = false;
```

This can go directly into your void loop() or another other function so you can call it as needed.

```
if (tempCondition && (!isOn)){
    irsend.sendRaw(ON, sizeof(ON)/sizeof(int),khz);
    isOn = true;
}
else if (othertempCondition && isOn) {
    irsend.sendRaw(OFF, sizeof(OFF)/sizeof(int),khz);
    isOn = false;
}
```

This will test the temperature and if true it will check if it needs to toggle using the isOn boolean.

If you want to supply the temperature ranges I can help complete the temp condition portions if you need it.

Comment: Thank you @UncleO for the suggested improvement